# Keyboard layout changes after reboot to US

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, language-support

Since a few weeks ago my keyboard settings keep changing to US after every reboot. I only have the Slovenian keyboard settings. Removed the US after installing the system months ago.
My system: Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit, AMD A6-3650 APU with Radeon(tm), 8GB on RAM

My locale:

```
locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Did you make the change in the right place? i.e. System Settings -> Text Entry

Comment: This sounds very similar to this known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1405118